# Joomla based owl Carousel

Tags: joomla-3.x

We have a Joomla based school website, and we want a owl carousel at the bottom that scrolls along.

I would like to link the images to their to websites.

I've looked everywhere to find the owl carousel code is but can't find it. There's a module for it, but it doesn't  have anything to alter the code like normal.

The site URL is: http://www.kibworthprimary.org.uk

Comment: You can create your custom module using the owl carousel code

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the extension? Have you tried contacting the developer of the extension or tried using a different extension that supports links? http://demo.joomclub.org/owl-carousel-joomla-module

Comment: as far as im aware the owl carousel does support links

Comment: [http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html] I have used this feature and created my own custom module. *But didn't gave any option in admin.

Comment: @Nathan I had a simular request last week and came to this post. If it helps, I created a module to turn any directory into a carousel. It's available on github and has lots of options: https://github.com/TVBZ/mod_directorycarousel

Answer (score 1):

The Owl Carousel codebase is freely available on Github:

https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel

If you need to implement something quickly you can just drop their code straight into a custom html module, just make sure that the wysiwyg editor is disabled first as it will probably strip out some things.

Comment: what about all off the css/js files where to they go?